# Android studio Emulator ( device unauthorized)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-8.0-oreo

I know that on a normal device I have to authorize the debugging process, but Authorizing it on an emulator is my first time.

I just installed my first emulator on my home pc to do some work stuff, and this poped up.

Any idea what is the cause or is it normal for android o api 26 google play SDK?

PS: I am using windows version at home.

Comment: possibly a duplicate, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26079838/1008011 you may have to also authorize on your emulator

Comment: i did those except unplugging my device since it is an emulator. i also started developer option on emulator but didn't get the prompt

Comment: Is your ADB integration enabled? You can try disabling it and then re-enabling it with `Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration`

Comment: disabled it then re-enabled it but still same unauthorized.

Comment: is it possible to create a new emulator and try again? if possible, try with a nexus 5 or nexus 5x (comes with google play and android-oreo)

Comment: Now i got another problem the emulator just black screens then crashes

Comment: Made a new emulator then fixed the black screen by changing the settings to use hardware graphics. And Bam every thing works thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Issue Resolved.

Step 1- Made a new emulator(Any).
Step 2- then fixed another problem the black screen by changing the settings to use hardware graphics.(Dunno if this problem was related to the bug)

And Bam every thing worked.

Comment: Except that for me there is no option to use hardware graphics.  The control exists, but you get exactly one choice: automatic.  It's grey and doesn't react to clicks.

Comment: Try to choose another emulator that isn't with a google play but a google api image. U can edit it then. Btw i updated to android 3.0 and it happened again for me so I switched to use genymotion.

Comment: I had same issue due to emulator with google play and resolved.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me too - Windows 10.

Comment: strange  but work

Answer (score 3):

when this happens you can request permission through the emulator
[demonstrative video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZE5UPBMQOMU)

But on the android Q api 29 emulator, when USB debugging is requested, the alert is gone before it can be confirmed, and the emulator bugs, preventing the emulator from connecting. I am not able to solve, just resetting and losing everything to solve.

Comment: This exactly happens to me, still an issue in February 2021

Answer (score 2):

TOOLS-->AVDMANAGER

[image: Image1]

[image: Image1]

Click on tooltip on the right side, you can see wipe data before doing that turn off your emulator.

This Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and tried all most all the suggested steps but following worked for me :

Steps:

1. Delete all the emulators with google play.
2. Create new emulator without google Play .
3. Now if you run the emulator, no authorization issue will be there

Or

An another approach to fix this issue is :
Steps:

1. let your emulator launch
2. Go to settings and enable the "USB debugger" option as you normally do in real time devices(5 click on Developer Options->build number)

Comment: Deleting ALL emulators and creating a new one without Google Play fixed it for me. After that I was able to create a new emulator with Google Play and that one worked as well. My problem started after moving my emulators to another storage partition, I probably didn't update all relevant .ini files.

Answer (score 1):

I found a mismatch between the .android/adbkey* files associated with the user running the process running adbd, and the same file associated with the user running the emulator.

I don't know about windows, but this is possible in Linux if you run adb as root to work around file permissions.

Fix: As the user running the emulator, type this into a command shell:

```
adb kill-server; adb devices
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete your Emulador, then Create an emulador without google play services, it can be Android Q (Android 11).
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work for me I had to start a new emulator from android studio with Oreo instead of Pie as a system image.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the  ~/.android folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue and its generated because I copied my SDK from one PC to another PC with Same configuration(Software and Hardware). Now I create an emulator on Pie and also tried Oreo but unauthorised comes for both.

Solution:
I delete my build tools, platform tools, emulator  only not complete SDK and download all of them again. Now I create my emulator for all type of Version and now no unauthorised error for all type of emulators.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep the Emulator on
2. Delete android folder using

   `rm -rf ~/.android`
3. Then restart adb

   `adb kill-server`
4. You should get a prompt on the emulator to allow USB Debugging
5. View the device status

   `adb devices`

This should fix the issue, I used this to fix when I was having issues launching the emulator from expo when making a react native app.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, none of the answers here worked, eventually found the following worked for me:

Create a new emulator without Google Play and start it, visual studio detects it on first start and the device will be authorised.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue on my Arch Linux while I'm developing Flutter apps, by deleting all of the emulator devices and create a new emulator without the Google Play Store.

Also, in the Graphics setting don't forget to choose Hardware Graphics instead of Automatic and the device will be available and detected.

Answer (score 0):

Create an emulador without google play services,
it can be Android Q (Android 11). It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it on Win10. When adding new device, choose Android 11 (without Google play)