# Android Studio does not detect emulator with play store?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, emulation

If I start an emulator without Play Store, my flutter project can be started on it however if it has Play Store then it does not find it. Even if I try to run the project with the flutter run command, it does not show the emulator although it is running.

Comment: what is the output of  the `flutter devices` command ?

Comment: Edge/chrome + `Device emulator-5554 is not authorized (You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.`)

Comment: You may find a solution on there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531829/device-emulator-5554-is-not-authorized-android