# Android Flutter Debug - Device Not Authorized

Tags: android, intellij-idea, flutter

Trying to debug my Flutter App in my Android (Asus zenfone 3 max) without success.

Trying to find the problem, I ran the command:

```
flutter doctor
```

Output:

> [!] Connected devices
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Too see more details:

```
flutter devices
```

> Device H1AXB600S423ZP4 is not authorized.
>
> You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.

**Considerations:**

- The debugger menu is enabled.
- Debugging USB is enabled too.
- The android is configured to transfer files (USB mode)
- Using Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 90, accepted):

On your device, go to Developer options-->Revoke USB Debugging and Disconnect your device. After reconnecting, you will get a RSA Fingerprint verification window, click on accept.
Done..

Comment: In my case toggling the USB debugging option initiated the creation of new keys.

Answer (score 15):

> According to [Eefret](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259923/eefret) - on Stack OverFlow, it's was a problem with the certificate dialog on Android device at the moment of the connect

The problem on Intellij was the same of the Android Studio, and this question fixed the problem:

[Android Studio - ADB Error - "...device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079838/android-studio-adb-error-device-unauthorized-please-check-the-confirmat)

Answer (score 1):

It happened because my android was recently updated. What worked was that I simply restarted the phone, and when connecting, the dialog appeared.

Answer (score 0):

for Linux developers the need to delete the content of .android, this worked for me and ofcourse i needed to enable USB debugging.