# emulator is not listed in connected usb devices even though the usb debugging is on in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, android-usb

I have enabled developer options and usb debugging mode in my emulator in android studio and it was working very well; it was listed in my connected usb devices and I could select it for running my application. But once I killed the process from command-line with `sudo kill -9` (since my computer was freezing and I had no other choice), my usb connected device list is empty.

**What I've tried:**

- I checked the developer options and usb debugging mode was still enabled.
- I tried to restart AVD manager from inside android studio; still got nothing in the connected usb device list.
- I tried to restart the android studio; still the same.
- I tried to restart the abd from command line with `sudo abd kill-server` and `sudo abd start-server`; nothing changed.
- I even rebooted my computer; still nothing shown in the list.

**Notes:**

1. I run android studio with root permissions; so I assume it can perform required actions with root access.
2. I checked connected usb devices from command line with `sudo adb devices -l` and my emulator was not listed there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43780475/4108803) by [Deepak Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6214316/deepak-kumar) and it worked. It is:

> 1. Go to **Phone Setting > Developer options > Revoke USB debugging**.
> 2. Turn off **USB debugging** and Restart Again.